# Record saves, promise rejects with custom REST adapter

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing an ember-data adapter for the DreamFactory services platform and am running into an issue I ***think*** is related to my adapter.

When updating an existing record the promise resulting from `model.save()` is **ALWAYS** rejected with an error of

`Assertion Failed: An adapter cannot assign a new id to a record that already has an id. <App.Event311:1> had id: 1 and you tried to update it with null. This likely happened because your server returned data in response to a find or update that had a different id than the one you sent`

Thing is - the request to the REST API and the response back from the REST API have the same ID!

#### Request (PUT)

`{
    "record": {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Sample Event",
        "date": "7/20/2013",
        "type": "success",
        "desc": "My first sample event."
    }
}`

#### Response

`{
    "record": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Sample Event",
            "date": "7/20/2013",
            "type": "success",
            "desc": "My first sample event."
        }
    ]
}`

The really weird thing is the record still updates properly both in the store **AND** in the database!

I have a working JSBin at http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mosek/1/edit that illustrates the problem. My custom adapter is on GitHub at https://github.com/ultimatemonty/ember-data-dreamfactory-adapter. The JSBin as well as my app are using Ember 1.7.0 and ED 1.0.0-beta.9

***EDIT***

The JSBin is attached to my personal hosted instance of DreamFactory - I haven't done anything with it outside of allowing access from JSBin but please be gentle :)

*** EDIT #2 ***

The `updateRecord` code is accessible on GitHub at https://github.com/ultimatemonty/ember-data-dreamfactory-adapter/blob/master/lib/ember-data-dreamfactory-adapter.js#L106 but here is the full method for reference:

```
updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);
    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record);
    var adapter = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // hack to make DSP send back the full object
        adapter.ajax(adapter.buildURL(type.typeKey) + '?fields=*', "PUT", { data: data }).then(function(json){
            // if the request is a success we'll return the same data we passed in
            resolve(json);
        }, function(reason){
            reject(reason.responseJSON);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The error message says you cannot post with an id. Why don't you remove the id? Ember Data expects the server to assign it.

Comment: @torazaburo this is an update to an existing model so I need the id to perform the update.

Comment: Try unloading the record from your store after the ajax request.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486542/ember-data-reloads-associations-when-including-a-response-in-a-put-request

Comment: An update is a PUT, not a POST.

Comment: @torazaburo apologies it is a PUT - OP updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter/serializer you're using is expecting you to return a response without the type in it:

```
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Sample Event",
    "date": "7/20/2013",
    "type": "success",
    "desc": "My first sample event."
}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tigiza/1/edit

You can see it here in the `extractSingle`, where it tries to wrap the payload in in another object with the type specified

```
EmberDreamFactoryAdapter.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    extractArray: function(store, primaryType, payload) {
        var namespacedPayload = {};
        namespacedPayload[Ember.String.pluralize(primaryType.typeKey)] = payload.record;
        return this._super(store, primaryType, namespacedPayload);
    },

    extractSingle: function (store, primaryType, payload, recordId) {
        var namespacedPayload = {};
        namespacedPayload[primaryType.typeKey] = payload;
        return this._super(store, primaryType, namespacedPayload, recordId);
    },
```

Your response looks like this:

```
{
    "record": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Sample Event",
            "date": "7/20/2013",
            "type": "success",
            "desc": "My first sample event."
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the serializer kicks in, and it looks like this:

```
{
    event:{
       "record": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Sample Event",
            "date": "7/20/2013",
            "type": "success",
            "desc": "My first sample event."
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

When really, the serializer should have it looking like this:

```
{ 
  event:{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Sample Event",
    "date": "7/20/2013",
    "type": "success",
    "desc": "My first sample event."
  }
}
```

You can see from the second example, the serializer wraps it in the type, then Ember Data says, hey, give me the id, so it looks at `event.id` which is undefined, because it lives under `event.record[0].id`

Comment: after looking at your example that makes sense. My understanding is that ED expects all REST response except DELETE to have a JSON root element - which this request does. Is that not the case for PUT responses?

Comment: Correct, but the serializer your using wraps the response in the type, but it ends up putting it two levels deep (answer updated)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! My real issue then is that I need for requests to be wrapped in the `record` element as that's what the DreamFactory API expects but I guess I need responses to be unmodified - I'm guess I need to write a custom `serializeRequestIntoHash` for my GET requests and let the `updateRecord` and `createRecord` methods use the default `serializeIntoHash` implementation?

Comment: Correct, and Ember Data has hooks to override, if each implementation returns differently (between save, and find etc)  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html `extractSingle`, `extractSave` etc.

Comment: When reading through the documentation I misinterpreted the `extractSave is an alias for extractSingle` as I was already overriding extractSingle therefore I was doing what was needed. Obviously not! Thanks again for the help!